# Calling C++ dll in VC++

Tags: c++

I am writing a application on VC++ using SAGEM MORPHO DLL's.
The DLL I am referring is MORPHO_SDK.dll
The function exposed is I

```
C_MORPHO_User::Enroll  ( US  i_us_Timeout,UC  i_uc_FingerNumber, T_MORPHO_TYPE_TEMPLATE  i_x_TemplateType,  
  UL  i_ul_CallbackCmd,  
  T_MORPHO_CALLBACK_FUNCTION  i_pf_Callback,  
  PVOID  i_pv_CallbackArgument,  
  I  i_i_CoderChoice,  
  UL  i_ul_DetectModeChoice   
 )
```

The way I am calling is

```
    int res;  
    C_MORPHO_User u,nw,idf;  

extern "C
" __declspec(dllimport) int Enroll  ( US  i_us_Timeout,UC  i_uc_FingerNumber, 
    T_MORPHO_TYPE_TEMPLATE  i_x_TemplateType,  
  UL  i_ul_CallbackCmd,  
  T_MORPHO_CALLBACK_FUNCTION  i_pf_Callback,  
  PVOID  i_pv_CallbackArgument,  
  I  i_i_CoderChoice,  
  UL  i_ul_DetectModeChoice   
 ) ;  
main()
{
int x=u.Enroll(0x15,1,MORPHO_PK_ISO_FMR ,0,NULL,NULL,MORPHO_MSO_V9_CODER ,MORPHO_ENROLL_DETECT_MODE);  
    printf("%d\n",x);  
}
```

While compiling I am getting these error

> 1.syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'u'
>   2.C_MORPHO_User : missing storage-class or type specifiers.

Is this the correct way to call the Dll. Kindly help in resolving the issue.

Comment: The immediate answer to your first question is *no*, it is *not* the correct way to 'call the DLL'. For starters you need the class definition from your .h file.

Comment: A couple of things: First you need to include the header file where `C_MORPHO_User` is defined. Second you should not declare a free-standing function `Enroll` as it's a member function of `C_MORPHO_User` and will be declared as part of the `C_MORPHO_User` class definition.

Comment: When I include the respective header files Header files it is giving errors like C_MORPHO_TemplateList' : base class undefined, C_MORPHO_FieldList' : base class undefined  ,syntax error : identifier 'C_MORPHO_TemplateList' etc...

Comment: Then you need to include the header file where `C_MORPHO_TemplateList` is defined, and so on until it builds.

Comment: And could you tell me the correct way to call the DLL function in to my application.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg I included all the header files and it is giving so many errors the same way I have mentioned above.

Comment: Do they not have an example application for the SDK?  If they do, try copying what that does.

Comment: Yes they have I tried and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included all the necessary Header files and it has resolved the issue.